# How can I only display the date from MySQL database?

Tags: vb.net, date, formatting

I only want to display the date from my database to a textbox which is a "yyyy/MM/dd" format. The problem is when I'm retrieving the data, it comes out as "28/01/2022 12:00:00 AM". How can I display just the date?

[image: This is the output after retrieving the data.]

Comment: When you say "date from my database to a textbox which is a "yyyy/MM/dd" format"  Do you mean it's stored as a string in the DB using that format or you specified an display format on the text box?  Perhaps update your question with the data retrieval method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a datetime field in SQL. You read into a vb.net variable

```vb
Dim myDateTime As DateTime = getDateTimeValueFromSQL()
```

or if you have a DateTime stored as a string in SQL (this is bad practice) you parse the string into a DateTime

```vb
Dim myDateTimeString As String = getDateTimeStringFromSQL()
Dim myDateTime As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myDateTimeString, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
' "dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss tt" here according to format in SQL
```

then if you want to change how it is displayed as a string, you just use a string format method

```vb
TextBox1.Text = $"{myDateTime:yyyy/MM/dd}"
' or
TextBox1.Text = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```